# Can I store an expression as a double? (or any variable)

Tags: c++, variables, formatting, expression, cout

This is a super simple question, but it has me confused.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
     double percentage = (3/100);
     
     cout << percentage << endl;
}
```

Why does this output zero? I was under the impression that expressions could be stored in variables...

Comment: Unclose this question!

Comment: `3/100` int division = `0`
`double percentage = 0`

Comment: @c0d3r May I ask why? The linked target addresses the OPs question as far as I can tell.

Comment: @cigien it's this guy's first question.

Comment: @c0d3r That may be the case, but that is not sufficient reason to reopen a question that was validly closed.

Comment: You can't store an expression in a `double`. You can only store the *result* of an expression.